# Writing a temp. array

Tags: java, arrays

Ive already wrote code that will take the temp for each month and then show and calculate the total, average, most and least rainfall for the year and output that. How do I replace the most and least rainfall with actually months names?

code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Rainfall
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String [] months={"Janurary","Febuary","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"};

    final int MONTHS = 12;
    double[] rain = new double[MONTHS];

    initRain(rain);
    double total = totalRain(rain);
    double average = averageRain(rain, total);
    int most = mostRain(rain);
    int least = leastRain(rain);
    // Decimal Format
    DecimalFormat digit = new DecimalFormat("#.0");
    // Output 
    System.out.println("The total rainfall of the year is " + digit.format(total));
    System.out.println("The average rainfall of the year is " + digit.format(average));
    System.out.println("The month with the highest amount of rain is " + (most + 1));
    System.out.println("The month with the lowest amount of rain is " + (least + 1));
  }

  public static void initRain(double[] array)

  {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++)
    {
      System.out.print("Enter Rainfall for month " + (x + 1) + ": ");
      array[x] = keyboard.nextDouble();
    }
  }
  public static double totalRain(double[] array)
  {
    double total = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < 12; x++)
      total += array[x];
    return total;
  }
  public static double averageRain(double[] array, double total)
  {
    return total / array.length;
  }
  public static int mostRain(double[] array)
  {
    double maximum = array[1];
    int value = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < 12; i++) {
      if (array[i] >= maximum) {
        maximum = array[i];
        value = i;
      }
    }
    return months[index];
  }
  public static int leastRain(double[] array)
  {
    double minimum = array[0];
    int value = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < 12; i++)
    {
      if (array[i] <= minimum) {
        minimum = array[i];
        value = i;
      }
    }
    return value;




  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like `mostRain` returns the month name. You just have to change its return type to String.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've got an index, and you've got an array of the names of the months, so... ?

```
String most = months[mostRain(rain)];
```

Comment: Thank you! One issue is that for some reason now with the months I have a 1 after each one.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that this code is not even compiling

see

```
public static int mostRain(double[] array)
  {
    double maximum = array[1];
    int value = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < 12; i++) {
      if (array[i] >= maximum) {
        maximum = array[i];
        value = i;
      }
    }
    return months[index];
  }
```

as it is expecting to be returned an `int` but you are returning a `String` (also index does not exist), so what you want is

```
public static int mostRain(double[] array)
  {
    double maximum = 0.00;  // change this too
    int value = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < 12; i++) {
      if (array[i] >= maximum) {
        maximum = array[i];
        value = i;
      }
    }
    return value; // change this
  }
```

then you can use it above like

```
System.out.println("The month with the highest amount of rain is " + months [mostRain (rain)]);
```

Of course, make the similar change for `leastRain` too.

Comment: Thank you! Runs great! Now Im trying to add a if statement after the user input of the temp if its negative. However when it catches the negative it moves onto the next month how do I have user reenter data

Comment: input = keyboard.nextDouble(); if (input < 0.00) {x--; continue;}